# How to demonstrate this inequality regarding the Rayleigh quotient is true

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

Let, $\phi(x) = \frac{x^* M x}{x^* x}$ where $x \in \mathbb{C}^{n}$ and $M \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$. How would one demonstrate that:
$$|| Mx - \phi(x) x||_{2} \le ||Mx - \kappa x||_{2},$$
for any $\kappa \in \mathbb{C}$, and where the norm is understood to be the euclidean 2 norm. I know that $\phi(x)$ is the Rayleigh quotient and it bounded above by the max eigen values of $M$ and the least eigen value of $M$, but I don't see how to demonstrate the above inequality, the triangle inequality does not seem to work. Any advice would be much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: What is the orthogonal projection of $Mx$ onto the line $\{\kappa x : \kappa \in \Bbb C\}$?

Comment: @azif00 Thanks, got it !